# Load More Posts with Multiple Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a page that uses Bootstrap's tabs, and when you switch between the tabs, it displays the first 3 rows for each section (everything after that is hidden).

The "Load More" button should show up at the bottom if there are hidden rows inside the tab panel, otherwise it shouldn't be displayed at all.

For example, the "All" tab/panel has 4 rows, and the 4th row has a `hide` class added (it would continue on like this if there were more rows), so the "Load More" button should show up (at least until the 4th row is not hidden anymore).

The "News" tab/panel only has 1 row, so there would never be a button when you activated this tab.

Without having to write a bunch of JavaScript for everything (when the page loads, when a tab is switched, when the button is pressed), how would you make this work correctly?

HTML and JavaScript can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/divspace/q11nxw2w/

Comment: Try this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_pagination.asp

Comment: That's pagination though. This is a button you press which adds more rows until there's none left to load.